# Physiologically, how can stress/anxiety cause neuropathy?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, brain, central-nervous-system

According to the Mayo Clinic, stress/anxiety can cause "pins and needles" (neuropathy) sensations all over the body.

**But how can this be?** My *understanding* of the sensory pathway is that sensory receptors (nerves) fire "pins and needles" signals to the brain whenever there is a lack of blood flow to them.

So does stress reduce blood flow to nerves? Is it a chemical reaction, perhaps where stress releases hormones that prevent the nerves from functioning correctly? Something else?

I'm looking for a biological/physiological/scientific explanation of what stress does to make nerves misbehave.

Comment: Something related http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24492/how-does-anger-relate-to-blood-pressure/24498#24498

Comment: Thanks @Jvrek (+1) - thats a pretty darned good answer to that question! So, can you (please) confirm my newfound understanding here: that stress produces various hormones that in turn regulate blood flow/pressure, which can then (under the right circumstances) reduce bloodflow to individual nerves? **Am I on track or way off?** Thanks again!

Comment: pins and needle sensations are not always pointed to lack of blood in nerves. http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24555/what-causes-feeling-of-feet-falling-asleep-to-be-delayed/25807#25807

Comment: Thanks again @Jvrek (+1) - I understand; however can you at least confirm that stress-induced neuropathy is chiefly a result of *hormones* which interact with neurons and cause them to malfunction? Thanks again!

Comment: There is a big difference between a pins-and-needles *sensation* and *neuropathy. Are you sure stress can cause *neuropathies*?

Comment: I wouldn't make drastic assumptions about cause-effect relationships or whether it is even neuropathy.  Anxiety may cause neuropathy-like symptoms or the symptoms may be a side effect of another biological process that is causing the anxiety. My personal theory is that there is something electrical going on, because magnesium is known to help mitigate anxiety symptoms.